# Neo4j Cypher Unknown Error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So I created a date dimension from this article
[a link](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/)

I modified it and added datestamp to Day node which is Month/Day/Year (string)

I added indexes on Year.year, Month.month, Day.day && day.datestamp

When I run this query:

> MATCH p=(day2:Day {datestamp:'1/1/2015'})-[:NEXT*]->(day {day:2})
>      return length(p)
>      limit 5

It takes 1667 ms to execute

When I modify the query to this:

> MATCH p=(day2:Day {datestamp:'1/1/2015'})-[:NEXT*]->(day {datestamp:'1/2/2015'})
>      return length(p)

After it runs for about a minute, it ends in the Unknown Error message.

My schema is:

> Indexes
>
> ON :Day(day)       ONLINE
>    ON :Day(datestamp) ONLINE
>    ON :Month(month)   ONLINE
>    ON :Year(year)     ONLINE
>
> No constraints

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share your database somewhere? Seems to be an interesting problem. Also which Neo4j version are you running?

Comment: Can you try to run `MATCH p=shortestPath(day2:Day {datestamp:'1/1/2015'})-[:NEXT*]->(day {day:2}) return length(p) limit 5`

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out.

Looks like the 1st query that runs 1667ms only runs and completes because of limit 5, it finds 5 records and stops further execution.

While the other keeps going and going until it runs out of juice.

I think solution in this case is constraint that indicates datestamp is unique which should prevent further execution.

Still interesting, considering there's about 2600+ records connected with HAS_NEXT so traveling through those relationships shouldn't be taking this long to find out that there's only 1 record that matches that query.